# What's the difference between 1N4004 diode and 1N4007?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, protection

I have a circuit with multiple diodes, and I was wondering if I could use a 1N4004 diode instead of 1N4007

[image]

Comment: The difference between 1N4001 to 1N4007 diodes is the maximum reverse voltage.

Comment: ok, so a 1N4004 diode which has 260V max reverse voltage would work perfectly with a 5V microcontroller, right?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to do.

Comment: it's for backpower protection

Comment: Why not add a schematic of what you’re willing to do? And did you consider reading the related questions and their answers?

Comment: @user2233709 I just added the schematic

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is the PIV rating (there are other somewhat subtle differences). If you are **absolutely certain** that more than 400VDC reverse bias is impossible in the circuit you can almost certainly use a 1N4004. Since there is little or no price difference between PIV ratings some may standardize on the higher voltage rated parts.

1N4006 and 1N4007 are made differently from 1N4001-4005- they are actually PIN diodes and can even be (ab)used in RF applications as such, but I doubt that is a concern to you. There are also significant differences in forward and reverse recovery time (often not even typical numbers are given on modern datasheets).  See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84471/what-is-the-difference-between-1n4001-and-1n4007-other-than-their-maximum-revers/221110#221110) answer, for example.

---

Edit: Since you've added a schematic- I see no reason you can't substitute the lower PIV 1N4004.

Comment: Wow I did not know that they were made differently +1 .When I was at school I thought that the number was put on after the doide was tested for PIV .

Answer (score 1):

The numbers represent PIV or peak      reverse voltage rating .You must check your circuit .The 4007 has the highest rating of the series at 1000V .When these slow thru hole general purpose diodes were in thier hayday many people rationalised on the 4007 because it would cover low voltages as well .When say in 1976 I designed a circuit I would  mark the hand drawn schematic with the part that I used in my birds nest .I bought lots of cheap 4007s and used them everywhere .The lower numbers with lower reverse voltage ratings did not appear to be any cheaper .If you use a lower PIV device assuming you have checked your circuit you will find that it has a lower foward voltage drop which is generally an advantage .

Comment: +1 for mentioning the lower voltage drop of the lighter dioides

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :
In an arduino circuit, yes

Since you tagged your question with "Arduino", i'm assuming your voltages are in the low range (5V, 12V, around those numbers).

The 1N400x diodes are a serie of 1A diodes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N400x_general-purpose_diodes) designed for general purpose rectifying.

If your voltage does not exceed the 1N4004's 400V limitation, it is perfectly safe to use.

However, you must be careful, since inductive power components (like motors) are known for generating Voltage spikes that could be greater than the diode's limit.